# Converting English Datepicker to Persian Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this script which uses Datepicker from jqueryui and want to change it to [Persian Datepicker](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/beta/datepicker/example/)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/persian.datepicker.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/persian.date.js"></script>
    <script src="js/persian.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pwt-date.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pwt-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
              $(".example1").pDatepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="example1" />
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works fine alone in a html file, but when i try to implement it into the script i'm modifing, then it does not work. Here is the code from the scripts i want to change:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">News Date :-</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="text" name="news_date" id="datepicker" value="" class="form-control">
  </div>
  </div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

*Both of the codes above work for them self! I'm going insane here. I can't find a solution for why i can't simply remove the old code and replace it with new.*

**UPDATE:** I added the script... and link to the footer.php and now i have the calender to choose. But when i chose today's date and save, then i want to edit the saved news i get the result on the right hand side!

[1 is the calender form add news page, 2 is the calender from edit new page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roZFO.png)

Comment: Are you moving your `<script>`'s to the new file? What's the issue? What error are you seeing? Did you debug?

Comment: I'm removing old codes and adding new codes from the link given. I now can see the calender, but the date acts very strange! See the image in my first post.